# Is there a way to adjust only the bottom padding of a chart's title in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

Based on the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html), the `padding` property of the title in Chart.js adjusts both the top and bottom paddings. However, I'd like to adjust only the bottom padding.

I've tried using a padding object:

```
title:{
    display: true,
    text:'Population of cities in California',
    padding:{
        left:0,
        right:0,
        bottom:30,
        top:0
    }
}
```

But this is probably not supported, because it just messed everything up and made the chart not even visible.
I've searched the documentation and googled a bit to see if this has been asked somewhere already, but I couldn't find any solutions.

Is there a built-in way to do this within Chart.js? If not, what would be the simplest workaround?

Comment: Looks like this is the source https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/5a83a8081110fa23654826d074393184e4282b8e/src/plugins/plugin.title.js#L123 And in the codebase, the toPadding function should be able to take that object. I did a js fiddle and reproduced your error. If this is unresolved, you may want to file an Issue on their github.

Comment: @swagrov Awesome, I'll look into that, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`title.padding`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html#title-configuration) takes the number of pixels to add above and below the title text.

There exists a workaround to add padding at the bottom of the chart title only. The [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. You can use the `afterDraw` hook to draw the title yourself directly on the canvas using [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.fillText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText).

```
plugins: [{
  afterDraw: chart => {
    var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.font = "18px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
    ctx.fillText('My Title', chart.chart.width / 2, 20);
    ctx.restore();
  }
}],
```

Together with this, you'll have to define top [padding](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html) for your chart. This determines the space between your title and the chart (the title bottom padding basicaly).

```
layout: {
  padding: {
    top: 80
  }
},
```

Please have a look at below code that shows how it could look like.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'bar',
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      ctx.save();
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.font = "18px Arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
      ctx.fillText('My Title', chart.chart.width / 2, 20);
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [10, 12, 8, 6],
      backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)', 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)'],
      borderColor: ['rgb(255, 99, 132)', 'rgb(255, 159, 64)', 'rgb(255, 205, 86)', 'rgb(75, 192, 192)'],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        top: 80
      }
    },   
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `padding` option under the `options.legend` object:

```
options: {
    plugins: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'My Title',
          font: {
            size: 17,
          },
          padding: {
            top: 10,
            bottom: 30
          }
      }
   }
}
```